# Symfony 3.0. Notice: Undefined index: name

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I got 2 entities. Users and UserRights, mapped by ManyToOne unidirectional association. When I try to create a new user with particular userRights (created before and already existing in table) I get the error **"Notice: Undefined index: name (...) in vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Entity\BasicEntityPersister.php at line 670"**. Here are my entities:

Users

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass = "AppBundle\Repository\UsersRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name = "users")
 */
class Users
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type = "string", length = 4)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy = "NONE")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type = "string", length = 20)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type = "string", length = 20)
     */
    protected $surname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type = "string", length = 30)
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity = "Departments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name = "department", referencedColumnName = "name")
     */
    protected $department;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type = "boolean", options = {"default" = FALSE})
     */
    protected $isActive;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity = "UserRights")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name = "user_rights", referencedColumnName = "name")
     */
    protected $userRights;
```

UserRights:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass = "AppBundle\Repository\UserRightsRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name = "user_rights")
 */
 class UserRights
 {
     /**
      * @ORM\Column(type = "integer")
      * @ORM\Id
      * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy = "AUTO")
      */
     protected $id;

     /**
      * @ORM\Column(type = "string", length = 20, unique = TRUE)
      */
     protected $name;
```

Controller:

```
/**
* @Route("/create/user", name="create/user")
*/
public function createUserAction()
{             
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();   
    $userRights = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:UserRights')->findOneByName('Admin');   
    $department = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Departments')->findOneByName('CN');   

    $user = new Users();
    $user->setId('josm');
    $user->setName('John');
    $user->setSurname('Smith');
    $user->setEmail('cos@gmail.com');
    $user->setIsActive(TRUE);
    $user->setUserRights($userRights);
    $user->setDepartment($department);

    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();

    return new Response(dump($user));
}
```

When using dump($user) everything looks just fine. The problem starts when I try to put the newly created user in database with persist + flush.

There are no errors considering syntax so I believe I do something wrong here. I assume either association or the `unique = true` is the problem here. I've read many topics and nearly all of them are all about the wrong syntax - product instead of products, customers instead of toCustomers etc. I checked my spelling a couple of times and I am quite sure it is correct.

Comment: Ok. I've changed `referencedColumn = "name"` to `referencedColumn = "id"` and used doctrine:schema:update --force command and it worked. However I'd like to see Admin, User etc not 1, 2 etc. as user_rights in my Users table. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Try marking `$name` as `@ORM\Id` because as far as I remember doctrine expects the referenced column to be identifier.

Comment: It works now, however, symfony wants me to also set Id when creating Depertment or UserRights although I have them marked as "AUTO". I've no idea why it is happening.

Comment: Maybe database is not configured properly to generate identifiers ? Try posting the specific error you're getting, also try `IDENTITY` / `SEQUENCE` instead of `AUTO` depending on your database.